# Create branch in Google Cloud source repository

Tags: google-source-repositories

I have created repository in google cloud source repository . It got created with default branch "Master" , i want to create repository with two branch or need to add branch but i am not getting option.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my query.

Go to Git terminal and run below
1)git: git branch 
2) git push -u  
Refresh repo in GSR.

Comment: Can you help in listing all the branches from repos(GSR) ?

Answer (score 0):

open the Git Terminal

1. `git branch <branch-name>`
   this command will create the local git branch
2. `git push -u origin <branch-name>`
   this command will push that branch local branch in google source repository

Now refresh the GCP source repository branch will reflect there
To get the access of that branch checkout to that branch

3. `git checkout <branch-name>`
   Now you can perform pull/push operations on that branch